# Download a file on the server with react native

Tags: android, react-native

I've been trying to download a file on the server for days, but the examples I see are from different url's, the examples are "example.com.br/file.extension"

In my case the url is -> F:\Inetpub\vhosts\ {url} \ {url} \ Clients \ {idClient}\Default\IMG.jpg

The data is coming from an api

```
getSingleDocument: async (documentoId) => {
    try {
      const auth = await AsyncStorage.getItem('auth');
      const req = await fetch(`${api}/${guid}/documentospadrao/ObterPeloId/?documentoId=${documentoId}&clienteId=${auth}`, {
        method: 'Get',
        headers: {
          Accept: 'application/json',
          'Content-type': 'application/json',
        }
      })
      const json = req.json();
      return json;
    } catch (err) {
      console.log('API::getSingleDocument: ' + err)
    }
  },
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved

I did this inside component Listdocuments.js

and this handleOpenFile is TouchableOpacity=onPress(handleOpenFile) and have a Menu like react-native paper that do this action

```
       <Menu
        visible={visible}
        onDismiss={closeMenu}
        anchor={
          <TouchableOpacity onPress={openMenu}>
            <Icon
              name="ellipsis-v"
              color="#505050"
              size={18}
              style={{ marginRight: '5%' }}
            />
          </TouchableOpacity>
        }>
        <Menu.Item onPress={handleOpenFile} title="Open file" />
      </Menu>


const handleOpenFile = () => { 
    const Path = data.PathDoc;
    const PathReplace = Path.replace("F:\\Inetpub\\vhosts\\example.com.br\\", "https://");
    
    const localFile = `${RNFS.DocumentDirectoryPath}/${data.Title}.${data.Extension}`;

    const options = {
      fromUrl: PathReplace,
      toFile: localFile
    };
    RNFS.downloadFile(options).promise
    .then(() => FileViewer.open(localFile))
    .then(() => {
    })
    .catch(error => {
      alert("Error.")
    });
    closeMenu();
  }
```

I used libs react-native-fs and react-native-fileviewer